# Macro Fails to Run After Importing Module

Tags: vba, excel

I have a private sub procedure called, 'Main', in a module called MMain. It's triggered on the Workbook_Open event and has been working without issue until I imported some modules from another workbook.

The error I am getting when the workbook is opened, or if I attempt to run the procedure from the Immediate window is:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

(The procedure runs fine if I click the Run button within the Main sub.)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Run "Main"
End Sub
```

Main doesn't have any arguments and the above will work if I rename it and the calling sub to 'Main2' for instance.

I can fix it, if I rename the procedure, but to be honest, I'd rather not, and I want to know how to fix it properly...

I suspect that because the other workbook that I imported these other modules from also contains a Main module, this could be what has caused the problem.

How would one fix this, other than using a backup, renaming the procedure, or, copying the code over to a new workbook?

Many thanks

Comment: Please include your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.

I had accidently changed the codename of a worksheet instead of the name of the sheet itself. I had renamed codename 'wksMain' to Main. I've changed it back to wksMain and it's now working.